# URL getting appended/duplicated twice while resolving DXA JAVA 1.5

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

We are using the standard DXA configuration and somehow the URL while resolving is getting appended twice. I checked all my Tridion configuration and do not find any place where this setting can be changed. Logs are :

```
    [6/20/17 10:40:37:774 EDT] 000000bd SystemOut     O 10:40:37.774 [WebContainer : 0] TRACE c.s.w.c.i.i.StaticContentInterceptor - preHandle: /dev/quote
    [6/20/17 10:40:37:774 EDT] 000000bd SystemOut     O 10:40:37.774 [WebContainer : 0] TRACE c.s.w.t.AbstractTridionLocalizationResolver - getLocalization: http://localhost:9081/dev/quote/dev/quote
    [6/20/17 10:40:37:774 EDT] 000000bd SystemOut     O 10:40:37.774 [WebContainer : 0] DEBUG c.t.d.p.MappingsResolverImpl - Getting publication mapping for http://localhost:9081/dev/quote/dev/quote
    [6/20/17 10:40:37:774 EDT] 000000bd SystemOut     O 10:40:37.774 [WebContainer : 0] DEBUG c.t.d.p.m.MappingsStrategyContext - Resolving url using strategy com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.mappingsstrategy.impl.StaticMappingsStrategy
    [6/20/17 10:40:37:774 EDT] 000000bd SystemOut     O 10:40:37.774 [WebContainer : 0] DEBUG c.t.d.p.m.i.StaticMappingsStrategy - Resolving: http://localhost:9081/dev/quote/dev/quote
```

[image]

We are also facing the duplicate asset path URL, Which is appending twice from publication mapping.

```
The Path extracted from the url is: [/system/v1.9/assets/scripts/xpm.js/system/assets/scripts/xpm.js]
```

Is this a known issue? or am I missing any jar/files? What is the use of `cd_wai.jar` is it related to this?

Comment: Just in this SG or you seeing duplicates in all SGs? If the former then I would check the publication properties and ensure you've not defined /dev/quote in both parent and child pubs?

Comment: This is happening for all the SG's. @Dylan